# Windows Form Application Randomly Crashes When Switching Form

Tags: c#, winforms, crash

so I have multiple forms, because I have multiple scenes. And so when someone clicks a button, like say, submit your username, it goes to the next form. This all works great, however, there's about a 1/5 chance that when I'm on the first scene, it doesn't switch when I click the button, and it just says "... (Not Responding)". I assume it isn't just the first one, but I wouldn't know since I can never get past there.

Here's the code behind the first form (the first form is just two buttons deciding what you want to do, and I haven't implemented the second button yet):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chat_Room {
    public partial class SceneOne : Form {
        public SceneOne() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //static void Close() {

        //}
        private void createRoomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Form2 scene = new Form2();
            scene.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is crashing, but it stops responding whenever I click on that button about one in every five times. And to be sure, I checked if it was just happening when I was debugging in Visual Studio, but no, when running the .exe file in the Debug folder, it crashes about 1/5 times. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's this code causing the problem?  And not something in `Form2`?  How have you confirmed this?

Comment: Without seeing what the second form does… speculation is about all you may get. My question would be… how does the second form "unhide” the first form? It could not possibly know anything about the first form without passing in the first form or making the first form a global variable. Therefore, when the code executes the line: `this.Hide();` in the button click event, there is no way for the form to “unhide” itself and therefore becomes “lost”. At least this is what the posted code will do.